# Unable to count records for associated model NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I tried to multiple ways to get the count of all job applications for the job model, that an employer has. When it comes to one job in particular (**job.job_applications.count**), it works. You can actually count the applications for that job in question. When you try to sum all job applications for all jobs. I may have overlooked something while setting up the relationships. I receive the error below:

line of code that breaks: `<%= current_employer.jobs.job_applications.count %>`

```
  undefined method job_applications' for #<Job::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x0000000011066998>
```

The code that I wrote beforehand, is below:

schema

```
  job
  create_table "jobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "job_title"
    t.text "required_exp"
    t.text "job_description"
    t.text "job_requirements"
    t.bigint "employer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.bigint "visit_id"
    t.index ["employer_id"], name: "index_jobs_on_employer_id"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_jobs_on_slug", unique: true
  end


 job applications
 create_table "job_applications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.string "user_resume_link"
    t.string "user_contact_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "user_first_name"
    t.string "user_last_name"
    t.bigint "job_id"
    t.index ["job_id"], name: "index_job_applications_on_job_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_job_applications_on_user_id"
  end
```

job.rb

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :employer
has_many :job_applications, dependent: :destroy
has_one :job_category
end
```

job_application.rb

```
class JobApplication < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :job
end
```

employer.rb

```
class Employer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_applications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :jobs, :through => :job_applications
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Employer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :job_applications, through: :jobs
end
```

And then just call `current_employer.job_applications.count`